# Motivation for the most experienced Stack Overflow contributors

Tags: discussion, answers, reputation, badges

I'm wondering what makes the Stack Overflow gurus, who have scored a huge rating (tens and even hundreds of thousands), constantly answer simple questions from beginners? It should not be sporty and not interesting? Please explain what motivates you, as it looks like you have already reached great heights and respect!

Comment: A complete idiot can get tens of thousands of reputation. I cite myself as proof. Why answer? Some of these people asking questions might not be complete idiots and only need a bit of a push to get past an otherwise simple problem that's between them and greatness. I've met too many people who could have been good at this job if only they hadn't been thrown off the deep end too fast, got frustrated, and went into a different career. The ability to crank out a linked list or perform some menial language screw-job assignments doesn't make you a good programmer and shouldn't be an impediment.

Comment: Especially when you consider some of the people doing the teaching and grading. Jeeeeze. Do more harm than good iff you're teaching from a C++ syllabus based on C assignment that were ported from Pascal some time in the 19080s.

Comment: I recently signed up (before that for many years I just scooped useful information from Stackoverflow) I am trying to earn a reputation by making the right answers (I don’t know how else to earn it in a useful and correct way). So while I'm trying to give the correct answer, gurus with tens of thousands of reputations (and I even often see one contributor with over 1 million reputations) are ahead of me.

Comment: [What motivates people to answer questions in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3742/598066)

Comment: I would say the rep gain. I'm not really high rep, but I imagine this is what motivates them. Also, the idea of curating and helping out on a site is awesome for many high rep users who are really smart people.

Comment: Imagine Jon Skeet answers this :p

Comment: [Rep for Nothing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3759/347908) and Badges for Free!

Comment: Supporting implied point in the question: answers by people who know what their are talking about prevent people who have no idea about the subject to gain reputation by posting some random unrelated stuff... Thus making SO less welcoming and harder to gain rep. Let's all stop answering whenever you know the answer. (That should be feature-request :))

Comment: Boredom. I don't have anything else to do

Comment: I believe Randall Munroe already summed this up some time ago: [**Duty Calls**](https://xkcd.com/386/)

Comment: @Cody almost a daily occurrence for me. GF asks "Did you sleep well?", me: "No, went to bed too late". Her: "Was someone wrong on the internet again?".

Comment: But, you still *slept well*, @CodeCaster, even if for only a limited time, because you corrected the wrongness. :-)

Comment: @Cody no, because in the nightmares that follow, I was actually the one being wrong.

Comment: Oddly it's my girlfriend who's usually up late at night fighting the good fight with The Wrong. If I'm up late at night it's usually because I'm trying to figure out how to undo the plot damage the players did in whatever RPG I'm running. Been slow on that front lately, though. COVID's a bigger <expletive deleted> than the most cunning player.